# Reloading a specific page only once with javascript in html code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am building a `jquery mobile` webpage . I use swiper slider plug in for image gallery. But navigation buttons and and pagination not works correctly without reloading page. When visitors enter the sixth page.

I just want to automatically  refresh only that page and only once. My image gallery in that page already. My html codes like this. I guess  we can do reloading webpage with java script codes. But although I do a lot of research, i could not find the solution. I will be grateful if you can help me.

```html
    <div data-role="page" id="page6">
       
      <div data-role="header">
       <div class="logo"></div>
       <div class="blueline"></div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content" class="bodycopy"><center>Resimleri Görmek İçin Yukarı Kaydırın</center>
        
        <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            
          <div class="swiper-slide" ><img src="images/image-1.jpg" alt="resim-1"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide" ><img src="images/image-2.jpg" alt="resim-2"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide" ><img src="images/image-3.jpg" alt="resim-3"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide" ><img src="images/image-4.jpg" alt="resim-4"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide" ><img src="images/image-5.jpg" alt="resim-5"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide" ><img src="images/image-6.jpg" alt="resim-6"></div>
           </div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        </div>
  
      <div data-role="footer" class="footer">
         <h4><a href="#page" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext">Button</a></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of my researches I have found a solution like this:

I divided my jquery mobile website in different pages. Like page1.html, page2.html So I did multiple page website. And created an external `.js` file for `swiper slider`. I put the `.js` link on end of `body` tag which page includes swiper slider codes in it.

Every  thing is okay now. It works very well. Before this editing all of the page codes were  in same file. Because of this swiper slider did not work correctly. Now i don't need to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.reload()` with `location = location` as a fallback for older browsers to reload the page with Javascript.

```html
<button id="reload" onClick="refresh()">Reload</button>
<script>
function refresh(){
 location.reload() ? location.reload(): location = location;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is button type of refreshing i think. I want the page to do this automatically only once and specifically.

Comment: @YusufDoğan Execute the function on page load: `window.onload = function(){refresh();}`

Comment: I am sorry for my inexperience. I found and tried this code* and wrote to #loaded part #page6 but when i enter the homepage it redirected me to #page6. I want when i am enter the 6th page this page automatically refresh by the server.  *Code: window.onload = function(){
    if(!document.location.hash){
        window.location = "#loaded";
    }
}

Comment: @YusufDoğan Place the code for refreshing inside the `head` of your sixth page.

Comment: i wrote the code like this  <div data-role="page" id="page6" "></div>
    <script>
window.onload = function();{ if(!document.location.hash){ window.location = "#page6"; } } 
</script>
   
  <div data-role="header">
   <div class="logo"></div>
   <div class="blueline"></div>
  </div>  it did not work unfortunately